# T-SQL String template variables replacement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pattern-matching

OK, I have a table with template data like this

```
TABLE TemplateFormula

Formula
--------------------
[val1]+[val2]+[val1]
[val3]/[val6]+[val1]
...
```

and a table with variables

```
TABLE TemplateData

Variable              Value
-----------           --------------
var1                  valueone
var2                  twovalue
var3                  othervalue
...
```

What is the optimal way of mapping value to template?

My solution was to create a cursor to go over all variables and replace value in template.
For example

```
DECLARE CURSOR c
FOR SELECT Variable, Value FROM TemplateData
...
UPDATE TemplateFormula
SET Formula = REPLACE(Formula, '[' + @Variable + ']', @Value)
WHERE Formula like '%\[' + @Variable + '\]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

But that's kinda slow (since there can be a lot of variables, in my case up to 10k variables), is there any faster way?

Comment: You could try dynamically constructing a single UPDATE that does a nested REPLACE, but I doubt it will be significantly faster, as you'd still use a cursor to construct the dynamic update.   Something like this might work faster in a CLR proc or a front end app.

Comment: This is not a task for sql. You will be better of leavong this to your presentation layer.